# How to run java class separately inside Android project in Eclipse?

Tags: java, android, eclipse

I am quite new to android and i am trying to run a voip project which I have downloaded from internet for learning purposes from this [**link**](https://github.com/emugabi/makcal).

I am facing a problem as it is an android project and it requires a java server to be running all the time to route the messages. But when i run the project as whole it runs as android project. I am not able to execute that server.java file as it is **included in the android project**.

As per my understanding it needs to be run seperately so that it can keep listening to the clients and then route the messages. May be i am missing something really basic in here.

Any suggestions to get it running would be really appreciated.

Comment: Maybe: http://help.eclipse.org/luna/index.jsp?topic=%2Forg.eclipse.jdt.doc.user%2FgettingStarted%2Fqs-12.htm

Answer (score 0):

You can create a new run configuration from within Eclipse and specify a new Java application.  The main class in the Server.java file should show up as the main runnable and you're done.

**Update:**

The server.java in that project was not in a /src folder, so Eclipse would not compile it.  Even if thrown into a separate src folder or project, the file still does not compile.  There is a class missing.

Comment: How can I create a new configuration from with in the eclipse??

Answer (score 0):

Looks like server.java is a standalone runnable java application.

Click the server.java file in the package explorer on the left pane and hit CTRL+F11, that should launch the server.

(If you want a more permanent solution that doesn't rely on having Eclipse open, you can right-click the server.java file and export it as a Runnable Java Application (JAR) then launch it via command line)

Comment: Ctrl+f11 launches full android app...I only need a wayout to keep the server.java class running..

Comment: Ah, I guess that's because it's witihin that android project. You could either create a new Java Application project and drag that .java file into the new project to run it, or you could do the more permanent solution I outlined in my answer.